# How to remove default selected value from Select2 Combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

In my web application, for the **select** element I'm loading **options** from javascript.

By default, it selected the 1st data in the **options**.

I wanted to remove the default selection or add a **placeholder** like *Select the item* likewise.

This is the summarized current code that I wanted to show you.

```
'<td width="40%">' +
 <select onchange="sendInfo(this)" class="form-select ItemId" data-id= '+counter+' name="Item_Id[' +counter +']" id="ItemId[' + counter +']" required="required" ' +
"</select>" +"</td>"


var selectElement = newRow.find("select"); 

 dropdownOptions.forEach(function (option) {

  var optionElement = $("<option>").val(option.Value).text(option.Text);          
  selectElement.append(optionElement);
  });

newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");
selectElement.select2({ width: "100%" });
```

Comment: https://select2.org/placeholders: _"For single selects only, in order for the placeholder value to appear, you must have a blank <option> as the first option in your <select> control. This is because the browser tries to select the first option by default. If your first option were non-empty, the browser would display this instead of the placeholder."_

Comment: @CBroe I went to your link and then I did ``newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");
            selectElement.select2({
                width: "100%", placeholder: "Select a item",
                allowClear: true
            });`` But it still not adding the placeholder, Now there is a close button and when I click it then placeholder appears.

Comment: _"you must have a blank <option> as the first option in your <select> control."_ - do you ...?

Comment: @CBroe forgot and now It is fixed. Thank you. How Can I mark your comment as an answer ?